# Is it possible to own a Jump Beacon in X3: Albion Prelude?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

Is it possible to own a Jump beacon in X3 Albion Prelude? And by that I mean hold it in your cargo bay, and have it show up green when deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible.  Obtaining one, however is very rare.  If you blow up the emergency response fleets there is a small chance one will be available as salvage.  If you deploy the beacon it will show up under your property page.

Comment: If you find ship with beacon in cargo, don't blow it, capture it!

Comment: @IvanSolntsev that might work too, but its very hard to capture emergency response fleeets.